# Which file formats can be played slower (or faster) than normal in Windows Media Player?

Tags: video, windows-media-player, codec, file-format, fast-forward

Some file formats (or some files that are coded used some codecs) can be played in Windows Media Player "slow" or "fast". I can enable this by right clicking on the movie while watching, clicking "enhancements" and then "play speed settings".

There, you can see a slider that has a blue part. That blue part is showing the usable part for the file. For AVI, the slider is blue between 0.5 and 2.0.

Is there a list of formats or codecs that support this feature?

Comment: It's the player, not the format. If WMP can't play a file with 2x speed for example, try VLC Media Player or MPC-HC (Media Player Classic Home Cinema). All the modern video players support this feature.

Comment: no wmp, also support this feature as I explained in the question; but not all the file formats... and I want to learn the supported formats

Comment: Well, check the files with "MediaInfo". It's a pretty neat app, which will let you know what is inside the .AVI container.

Answer (score 0):

Like Shiki said early, it is the player that is the dependency on the speed of play. What codecs the player supports is another question.

WMP pretty much supports whatever codecs you install through the OS.

VLC installs with its own codecs for the most part.